# Perfect Hash for 7-long array of values from 0 to 46

Tags: python, hash, hashtable

I wanted to ask if someone on the forum has had something similar and could share the experience.

I need to create a perfect hashing algorithm for a finite set of values. This value consists of 7 numbers varying from 0 to 46, so the min value would be `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` and the max one would be `[46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46]`.

I could use the trivial 'use value as index', but it yields

```
46,      |464,    |646,    |464,     |646
trillions|billions|millions|thousands|
```

variations. And that's too much, considering there is only `133784560` possible values (according to calculations).

There is also a way to create a 7-dim array, each dimension 46 in size. But it is an overkill again.

There must be a way. Does anyone has any experience?

Comment: "considering there is only 133784560 possible values (according to calculations)"—I think you should check your calculations.

Comment: What sort of constraint leads to that figure of 133784560?